# Filter xml element removing duplicated child node with groovy xml slurper

Tags: xml, groovy, xml-parsing, duplicates, xmlslurper

I need to filter an xml list so to get all the "element" with no duplicates.
Input:

```
<List>
<element>
    <field1>A</field1>
    <field2>1</field2>
</element>
<element>
    <field1>B</field1>
    <field2>2</field2>
</element>
<element>
    <field1>B</field1>
    <field2>2</field2>
</element>
```

output

```
<List>
<element>
    <field1>A</field1>
    <field2>1</field2>
</element>
<element>
    <field1>B</field1>
    <field2>2</field2>
</element>
```

How is it possibile to achieve this with XmlSlurper or XmlParser in groovy?
Thank you.

Comment: Please add the code you have tried and how it failed (e.g. errors,
stacktraces, logs, ...) so we can improve on it.

Comment: Is it possible to use findAll and to remove dplicates with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this is an option:

```
import groovy.xml.* 

def data = '''
<List>
<element>
    <field1>A</field1>
    <field2>1</field2>
</element>
<element>
    <field1>B</field1>
    <field2>2</field2>
</element>
<element>
    <field1>B</field1>
    <field2>2</field2>
</element>
</List>'''

def xml = new XmlParser().parseText(data)

def writer = new StringWriter() 
def result = new MarkupBuilder(writer).List { 
  xml.element.unique { 
    it.field1.text()
  }.each { n ->
    element { 
      field1(n.field1.text())
      field2(n.field2.text())
    }
  }
}

println writer
```

which when run prints:

```
─➤ groovy solution.groovy
<List>
  <element>
    <field1>A</field1>
    <field2>1</field2>
  </element>
  <element>
    <field1>B</field1>
    <field2>2</field2>
  </element>
</List>
```